# Python coding best practices

Tags: python, oop

Is it a good idea to handle all the arguments in the constructor? instead of handling them in the particular methods where the arguments are actually needed?

### Method 1:

```
   def __init__(self,name,rollno,dob,city,state,zip):
        self.name=name
        ..
        ..
        self.zip = zip
   def address(self):
        return self.city+self.state+self.zip
   def unique_identifier(self):
        return self.name+self.rollno
```

---

test.py

```
example = Example("Programming","941","1997-09-07","Nashville","TN","37311")

print(example.address())
print(example.unique_identifier())
```

---

### Method 2:

```
Class Example: 

   def address(self,city,state,zip):
        return self.city+self.state+self.zip
   def unique_identifier(self,name,rollno):
        return self.name+self.rollno
```

---

test.py

```
example = Example()

print(example.address("ab","cd","111")
print(example.unique_identifier("Programmer","123")
```

Any explanation/reasoning to help understand Which method is more preferable for best practices.

Comment: This is likely going to be closed for being opinion-dependent, but in your case I think I would clearly lean towards the first one. In fact, I would do a method three, where you set "address" in the constructor. (Unless you want the address to change, in which case you should look into the `@property` decorator.)

Answer (score 1):

Either is fine, it just depends on if the data belongs to the object (method 1) or if the data comes from outside the object (method 2). It can also be a mix of both. A short example:

```
class Person:
   # store data specific to the instance
   def __init__(self, name, birthdate, hometown):
      self.name = name
      self.birthdate = birthdate
      self.hometown = hometown
   
   # here I only need data from the instance
   def introduce(self):
      print("Hello, I am", self.name,
            ", I come from", self.hometown,
            " and was born on ", self.birthdate,
            ".")

   # food shouldn't be part of the Person,
   # so it is passed in as an argument
   def order_food(self, food):
      print("I am ", self.name,
            " and would like some ", food, " please.")
```